# Piping Perl script output to head -n 10 kills script after printing 10 lines

Tags: linux, perl, unix, unix-head

My Perl script outputs and logs many lines of text, and it does some cleanup and compresses some logs in an `END` block.

The problem is when you do something like this on the command line:

```
perl myscript.pl | head -n 10
```

This causes the script to die as soon as it outputs 10 lines, so the `END` block doesn't get executed and the logs don't get compressed. Is there a way to get around this and make sure the code in my `END` block is still executed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the reading end of a pipe is closed, and the writing process tries to write something to a pipe, then the writing process receives a `SIGPIPE`. The pipe is called *broken*.

We can capture this event like

```
local $SIG{PIPE} = sub {
  # This is our event handler.
  warn "Broken pipe, will exit\n";
  exit 1;
};
```

This would gracefully exit your program. Instead of installing a sub as event handler, you could give the string `IGNORE`. This would let your script carry on as if nothing happened.

```
# print will now return false with $!{EPIPE} true instead of dying
local $SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this solves the problem; I cannot actually reproduce a behaviour at the moment that triggers a sigpipe.

Comment: This seems really inconsistent. I wrote a script to test this http://pastebin.com/t6P8baQ7 and running it a few times (`perl test.pl | head`) gave just about every imaginable result. Sometimes it reached the `PIPE` handler, sometimes it didn't, other times the `PIPE` handler was delayed. Setting `$SIG{'PIPE'} = "IGNORE"` seems like the only predictable option.

Comment: @AKHolland Both pipes and signals are async IPC. It is not suprising that each run produces slightly different output. The signal may well be sent after the loop has already terminated; the buffer that is switched off by `$|++` isn't neccessarily the only buffer.